# How can i add <span></span> to catalog counting ( Opencart catalog module )

Tags: opencart, catalog

My english is not good so please forgive me.

I want my catalog name like this

```
Productname <span> product count </span>
```

Here the code of product.tpl

```
 <ul class="box-category">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <li>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
      <li>
        <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I think it some where in module/product.php

```
    $children_data[] = array(
                'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
            );      
        }

        $this->data['categories'][] = array(
            'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
            'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $total . ')' : ''),
            'children'    => $children_data,
            'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
        );  
    }
```

But i dont know how to insert it, please help me !
Plz!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: sorry, it from module/catalog.tpl and module/catalog.php please help me please

Comment: $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

    $total += $product_total;
i think it in here, sorry because i dont want this question become too long so i dont post full the module/catalog.php, its my mistake

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays should look like this:

```
$children_data[] = array(
    'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
    'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' <span>' . $product_total . '</span>' : ''),
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
);

$this->data['categories'][] = array(
    'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
    'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' <span>' . $total . '</span>' : ''),
    'children'    => $children_data,
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
);
```